# Pocketsphinx Python get_raw_data

Tags: python, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I'm trying to implement a keyword based personal assistant
My issue is my grammar is set up so that after I detect the keyword, I still need to use it in my grammar,but switching to jsfg mode discards that utterance

Therefore I need to use **Decoder.get_raw_data** and **Decoder.process_raw_data** in but in Python there is no implementation for **.get_raw_data** method present in C/C++ implementation

Is there any way I could use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement Python part in swig unfortunately.